# Check amount of threads in AWS S3 pool using Java SDK v1.11.520

Tags: java, amazon-s3, java-8

I want to include in my s3Client client a metric for checking how many threads are remaining in the S3 pool.

somewhere in the construction of the s3Client:

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().build()
```

i.e. if I have  20 connections and 3 are stuck or in use I would like the metric to show me that I have 17 free connections.

Thanks.

Comment: `AmazonS3Client` class is marked as `@ThreadSafe`, so one client object can be used in multiple threads concurrently. You can use `Executors` for creating a `ThreadPoolExecutor` using `newFixedThreadPool`, and then use the `ThreadPoolExecutor` class' `getActiveCount()`, `getPoolSize()`, etc. methods to get the details of completed count, pending, etc. All those threads may share the singleton `AmazonS3Client` object.

Comment: There is no JDK v1.11.520. Please review the version mentioned.

Comment: your right SDK 1.11.520